# data visibility in different shared library in linux

Tags: c++, dynamic, shared

Suppose there is a program which will dynamically load two shared library and there is a message allocated in library A. I want to know if it is possible for library B to use that message.

Edit: Since it is just in the design stage, there is no "real code".

in shared library A:

```
void process()
{
 msg_ptr =  new message();
 send(msg_ptr); //send the msg address to library B
}
```

in shared library B:

```
void process()
{
 recv(msg_ptr); // at this point how can library B access the msg address
}
```

Comment: shared library or shared memory?

Comment: give some example code snippet

Comment: The `send` and `recv` are names of operations, that are used for passing messages *between processes*. If that's not what you mean, your question is really confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edit): Ok, the question is somewhat confusing because the `send` and `recv` imply inter-process communication and it seems not to be the case, so:

Short answer: Yes, it does not matter which library, static or dynamic, does the allocation. It is always process-wide.

Shared library means the code is stored on disk once, but does not mean anything at all (that would have effect on usage) at runtime.

Allocation does not care whether it's done from library or application code. Each process has just one heap from which it does all allocations. This heap is accessible by all code running in context of that process and never accessible by any other process (even if using the same code). In fact, the `operator new` itself lives in another shared library (`libstdc++.so`) and it just calls `malloc` from yet another shared library (`libc.so`). And each shared library appears only once in each process, even when more than one other shared library depends on it (this may in some corner cases be different on Windows).

At runtime, pointer in one address space is never ever valid in address space in another process, so passing pointers in messages between processes makes no sense, ever. It is perfectly OK between different threads of the same process though.

Comment: Since a application loads two shared library, I thought it is in the same address space which is in the that application.

Comment: @Michael D: No. Address space is a table saying what should be at which address. This table is completely independent for each process. Plus, as I said, `new` allocates from the heap, which is completely private to process (shared libraries don't have their own heaps, processes do).

Comment: yes. so if one application (i.e. one process) loads two shared library, the heap is shared, right?

Comment: @Michael D: Yes. The process has only one heap. A `new` in either shared library executed in context of that process will allocated from that one heap. In fact, the `operator new` itself lives in third shared library (`libstdc++.so`) and all it does is it calls `malloc` that lives in fourth shared library (`libc.so`). The two shared libraries refer to the same  ... so you mean you never thought about 2 processes?

Comment: Yes. I only think about one process.

Comment: The `malloc` example hit the nail on the head.